# Drupal SQL "Select count distinct"

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-6

Can someone help debug this?

Currently my script throws this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in includes/common.inc(1695) : eval()'d code on line 38

and I've narrowed it down to this SQL statement. It appears that counting results rows in Drupal isn't as straight forward as I'd hoped.

```
$sql_checkIP = "SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT v.hostname 
FROM {pollfield_votes} v 
WHERE v.hostname = '%s' AND v.nid =%d)";

$result0 = db_result(db_query($sql_checkIP, $hostname, $nid));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I see is that you haven't written any alias for the derived table

```
$sql_checkIP = "SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT v.hostname 
FROM {pollfield_votes} v 
WHERE v.hostname = '%s' AND v.nid =%d) as new_derived_table";
```

Now, I don't know how many results you'll have with your query, but `db_result` is used only when you have only one row as a result. If it's the case okay, otherwise you should implement a loop like:

```
$result = db_query($sql_checkIP, $hostname, $nid);
while($res=db_fetch_array($result)){  
  $count_row = $res['COUNT(*)'];  
}
```